# g-suite Google Calender Apps script On Event Save/Update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

First of all, i am new to Google Workspace and this is the first time i am developing an addon.
I am trying to develop a Google Workspace(gsuite) Addon using Google Apps Script,
My main objectives are:

1. Whenever i `create/save/update` an event in Google Calender, i want to make an alert asking for `ok` and `cancel`, if i click **cancel** the event should not be created and if i click **ok** then the event should be created and the script function should call my API endpoint with the following parameters:

   ```
    {
        summary: summary_of_the_event,
        created: event_created_or_updated_date,
        googleCalendarId: calender_id
    }
   ```

Here is the reference to Apps script Google calender:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app

I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you're speaking to the [updated event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#eventupdated) I believe the trigger occurs after the the event is updated.  This is the link to [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#eventupdated)  Perhaps there are new events that haven't been documented I can't speak to that but as far as I can see there is no on creation event.

Comment: @Cooper thanks for that, can you please provide me a simple example to understand how that updated event should be triggered?

Comment: I've never used it but I suppose that it's triggered when you edit an event.  It might be worth looking at JSON.stringify(event object) to see what the real object contains.  Often it contains more than that which is shown in the documentation.

Comment: where's your doGet?

Comment: @Baby_Boy sorry i haven't written it, as i am new

Comment: your code won't work without it, its what it runs when it first deploys

Comment: @Baby_Boy as the Calendar class doesn't have any sort of UI, so how can we do it with html ? can you please provide me a code. I am struggling with it very hard

Comment: don't you have a .gs file?

Comment: yes i do have that, i can write doGet and use an HtmlService but i dont know how to show the data inside html file, 
On the other hand, can i do something with the CardService?

Comment: did you try ```doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
} ``` replace index with the name of your html file

Comment: Yes you are saying right, but that doesn't show the addon in the addon sidebar.

Comment: try the gsuite template when creating the program

Answer (score 1):

### Some thoughts about calendar add-ons

- `CalendarApp` features the [installable calendar trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) with the [specification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_calendar_events):

  > Calendar triggers fire when a user's calendar events are updated (created, edited, or deleted).

  - Installble triggers [can be used](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#installable_triggers) in Google Workspace add-ons
  - Howver, this installable trigger only fire after the event has been created / updated, so it can help you to cancel event creation, but rather no manually delete the event a posteriori.
  - Mind also that the when the trigger fires, it does not give you any information about the created / updated event - you have to manually find this event e.g. by querying for the least created / updated event in user's calendar.

- Google Workspace Calendar add-ons feature the [manifest trigger](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-triggers#manifest_triggers)  for [updating calendar events](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/building-calendar-interfaces#updating_calendar_events) `calendar.eventUpdateTrigger`

  - Thereby:

  > This trigger only fires if the user makes one or more of the following edits:
  >
  > Adds one or more attendees.
  >
  > Removes one or more attendees.
  >
  > Adds or switches to a different conferencing solution.
- Google Workspace Calendar add-ons also feature the manifest trigger [calendar.eventOpenTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#Calendar.FIELDS.eventOpenTrigger)

  - It fires when you open an event (this is what you want!).
  - However, this work only for already existing events - not when a user opens the Calendar UI interface to create a new event

- Instead of letting a user create / update events through the regular Calendar UI, you can use [Card Service](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/calendar-actions#adding_attendees_with_a_callback_function) to create a custom add-on interface where the user can specify that he wants to create an event

  - Within the card interface, it is easier to implement an ok / cancel functionality (as a card) and then (in case "ok" is clicked) create an event for the user programmatically.

Comment: thanks man for pointing me in the right direction, i have managed to edit the manifest and enable the interface.
Now i want to show an alert to the user but i am unable to find an example on how to implement an alert box with yes and no functionaity

Comment: Not sure if you can implement alerts, but you can embed a [button set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button-set) within the card and implement the "Ok/Cancel" functionality with [onClickAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setonclickactionaction).

Comment: Do you know how can i stop and again resume whenever a google event is saved/updated?

Comment: Stop and resume what?